# Can I listen to a command prompt?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to be able to access the command prompt from a web browser. It doesn't sound like a possible thing?

So my options:

- In the browser do a server request and that platform (.NET/IIS?) can
  talk to a command prompt (Can it be done?)
- Write an app that can listen to a command prompt and its I/O

Let me know if I'm talking crazy. If not, any info would be appreciated!

Comment: What does "access the command prompt" mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to be able to give input to a command prompt and listen to an output with a separate application besides the command prompt.

Comment: I think the question is "how I can implement telnet in browser". Obviously it is possible, but I'd strongly recommend to get redirect of command prompt working in local application before jumping to stateless HTTP protocol implementation...

Comment: @Alexei Telnet/SSH would be good it I were doing remote or network-based stuff. Eventually, I'd like to look into this, but baby steps :)

Comment: How would you imagine this working anywhere other than your dev box?  In prod the user on the other end of the browser isn't going to have a command prompt window open on your web server

Comment: This exercise isn't for it to talk to other 'boxes' it's more or less just interested in what it can do in a command prompt/for the user and just consider it in a browser. I say .net/iis because that is the communication platform I am choosing out of the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Process.Start()` in C# and set `Redirect*` to true in the `ProcessStartInfo`.

You can then read and write to/from the standard in/out streams of the process you create.

Comment: Does the System.Diagnostics have a method to listen and transcribe the Processes? Can I do Process.Start("cmd)") and then listen to the I/O i can perform on the application?

Comment: Yes.  Read the rest of my answer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx

Comment: Hmm, setting the Redirect to TRUE seems to block the  conosole from finishing the process. I did a streamreader readLine and I can output the command prompt command, but it seems the streamreader.endofstream is blocking the process to finish...Let me know if you want to see my code. Thanks,

Comment: @Vinny: Is the process waiting for input?

Comment: Probably? In the link you passed earlier in the do/while I'm doing this:
   Debug.WriteLine("~>" + reader.ReadLine());
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                }
                do
                {
                    var x = reader.ReadLine();
                    Debug.WriteLine(x);
                } while (reader.ReadLine() != "");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18370/discussion-between-vinny-and-slaks)